# Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is asssuming that it has crashed

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, vps

I have been trying to look on Stack Overflow to fix my issues with running a Python script. I have had the error 127 and this error a lot of times after installing other drivers (`pybrower`, `chromium-chromedriver`, `chromium-browser`) it still doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/LowCSFloat.py", line 43, in driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in init super().init(command_executor=executor, options=options) File"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 209, in init self.start_session(capabilities) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps) ["value"] File "/user/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selnium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Code:

```
extension_path = r'/root/Chrome for Testing/User Data/Default/Extensions/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg/3.2.0_0'
userdata_path = r'/root/User Data'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/lib/chromium-browser'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--load-extension={extension_path}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={userdata_path}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--headless=new')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--disable-dev-shm-usage')

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options

#code...
```

In order to make my script work I have to use a Google extension and be logged in on a website. This was working on my laptop. I used a path for the extension in `Chrome for Testing/User Data/Default/Extensions` and a path for the user data `Google/User Data`. After that the script does the rest of its work. My idea was to run it on a VPS. I have uploaded the files using SFTP, but I haven't been able to get it to run. I think this is due to the difference between versions of Browsers and Drivers or me forgetting to install other dependencies.

Things I tried that didn't help me:

sudo apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libnss3 libgconf-2-4 libfontconfig1
sudo apt-get install gconf-service
sudo apt-get install chromium-driver
chmod +x /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chrome
pip install pybrowser
pip install webdriver-manager (this made me change my code so it automatically installs a driver. I still use it, but it didn't fix the issue)

I also often tried to do ls / find / whereis to find the driver but that didn't work either. even tho there's a chrome driver I couldn't find it while doing that. I think it's because it's located in /usr/lib. I am not sure.